# Workflow-Core versus ElsaCore

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, sharepoint-workflow, power-automate

I am looking for some alternatives to MS Flow/Power-Automate to save money. How are these two solutions different? Advantages of each? Downsides?

https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/

and

https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core

We are primarily converting some older Lotus Notes apps to Sharepoint and other things and need to trigger workflows after a form is submitted. Somtimes 5 layer deep approvals, etc. I know Sharepoint and Workflow Foundation aren't really being actively developed anymore as well.

Comment: what did you end up using? i am looking for similar comparison

Comment: Nothing yet. Still trying for Power Automate